# How to get object field from 'each' iterator. Wrong 'this' context

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have prototype and "class" named Parser like this:

```
function Parser(year){
  this.table = [];
}

Parser.prototype = {
  _months: [0, 3, 6, 12, 15, 18, 27, 30, 33, 39, 42, 45], 

  getCalendar: function(year){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.domain.com/" + year,
      success: $.proxy(function(data, status, xhr) {
        $(Parser.prototype._monthes).each(function (i, v){
          // problem in this line: how I can get field 'tabel' from my object of Parser class
          this.table.push(parseInt($(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data)[v].innerHTML, 10));
        });
}, this)});
```

// problem in this line: how I can get field 'tabel' from my object of Parser class

```
this.table.push(parseInt($(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data)[v].innerHTML, 10));
```

I can't move 'table' into prototype because in each instance I should have own field

I try this:

```
var _table = []
$(Parser.prototype._monthes).each(function (i, v){
  _table.push(parseInt($(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data)[v].innerHTML, 10));
});
this.table = _table;
```

It works, but it's dirty. Any other way?

Comment: You could use another `proxy` call for the callback of the `each` method.

Comment: Notice that you shouldn't use `$(…).each(…)` on data, but only on DOM objects. Use a plain for-loop or `$.each(…, …)`.

Comment: Btw, please fix `monthes` to `months` and `tabel` to `table` :-)

Comment: 'Notice that you shouldn't use $(…).each(…) on data, but only on DOM objects. Use a plain for-loop or $.each(…, …)'  Please, tell why? 'months' and 'tabel' it's a transliterations from my language :-)

Comment: @Alexey [jQuery(elementArray)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray) - The only kind of array you're supposed to pass to `$()` is an array of DOM elements, not ordinary values. From that page: "_When passing an array, each element must be a DOM element; mixed data is not supported._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all this `$.proxy` madness and just use a closure. Also note that I changed `$(...).each` to `$.each(...)` since it's more appropriate.

E.g.

```
getCalendar: function(year) {
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/" + year,
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            $.each(that._monthes, function(i, v) {
                that.tabel.push(parseInt($(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data)[v].innerHTML, 10));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

On another note, data retrieval operations shoulnd't have side effects, unless that's what the function's name describes. It makes your code inflexible and harder to understand. Nothing in `getCalendar` states that it might mutate the state of the object.

You should probably have something like `this.getCalendar().then(...)` instead.

Comment: And you can even use the vanilla `that._monthes.forEach(callbackFunction, context)` in case you don't have requirements about IE8 support and below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.proxy()` all the way down:

```
getCalendar: function(year){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.domain.com/" + year,
      success: $.proxy(function(data, status, xhr) {
        $(Parser.prototype._monthes).each($.proxy(function (i, v){
          // problem in this line: how I can get field 'tabel' from my object of Parser class
          this.tabel.push(parseInt($(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data)[v].innerHTML, 10));
        }, this); 
      }, this)});
   })
}
```

Another option is to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). In either case, I recommend factoring out your functions to avoid getting lost in all those braces and parentheses. Here's how you could do this with `bind()` (and I've corrected the spelling of "table" and "months"):

```
Parser.prototype = {
  _months: [0, 3, 6, 12, 15, 18, 27, 30, 33, 39, 42, 45], 

  _handleCalendarSuccess: function (data, status, xhr) {
      var values = $(".wstd tr td div.wstd_type2", data);

      $.each(this._months, function (i, v) {
          this.table.push(parseInt(values[v].innerHTML, 10));
      }.bind(this));
  },

  getCalendar: function(year){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://www.domain.com/" + year,
      success: this._handleCalendarSuccess.bind(this)
    });
  }
};
```